# Android : status bar color change for API level below 21

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-theme, android-styles, android-statusbar

I am trying change status bar color for API level lower than 21.By changing the color primary in Theme style we can change the color in status bar for the API level 21.

[image: Playstore]

I am looking for how to change the status bar color for lower version

Can any one please help me ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Changing the color of statusbar is available from Lollipop

but actually you could change the color of statusbar for Api >= 19

inside the style of value-v19 put

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

        <style name="AppTheme" parent="MaterialDrawerTheme.Light">
                <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
                <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
                <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
                .....
        </style>
</resources>
```

the background color of the status bar will became transparent color, and for coloring it you just put a background color in your to your app so the status bar will take that color

hope that was clear and helpful

Comment: This is good, how can I changed it's color instead of translucent?

Answer (score 4):

Changing status bar color feature is only available from Lollipop onwards. Lower OS versions doesn't have this feature. There is no way for you to change the status bar color in pre lollipop devices.

Comment: i'm not agree with this, what about this library? https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

Comment: Thats not exactly like material design. With that we can create only translucent status bars. And it can be done in only API>=19.

Answer (score 3):

Status bar coloring is not supported till date in latest version of [`AppCompat v7:23.1.0`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) too.

Take a look at [Android developers blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

**From the post :**

*On older platforms, `AppCompat` emulates the color theming where possible. At the moment this is limited to coloring the action bar and some widgets.*

Which  means the AppCompat lib will only color status bars on Lollipop and above.

Comment: You'd think. *Sigh*. Sometimes design choices made by Google is puzzling. Like what do they smoke over there?

Answer (score 0):

<< This is not the best solution (but might be the only one), but it works >>

Below API lvl v21, you can change the status bar color by changing your ***colorPrimaryDark*** (sometimes ***colorPrimary***) attribute in the ***styles.xml*** file and inside the ***theme*** that you are using.

Now this may or many not be feasible for you and it may seem like a hack or just even be obvious to you. But I'm just posting it here because it worked for me and I really hadn't used the colorPrimary or colorPrimaryDark so I had no problems with it.